# Dictionary containing array object is crashing while passing it to WatchKit Extension

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdictionary, apple-watch

I have created dictionary inside a watchkit extension delegate method as:

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application handleWatchKitExtensionRequest:(NSDictionary *)userInfo reply:(void(^)(NSDictionary *replyInfo))reply {

NSDictionary *dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:customEntityArray,@"keyString",nil];
NSLog(@"dict is:%@", dict);
reply(dict);

}
```

where customEntityArray is a array of custom Class Objects.

when i am trying to log dict - it prints correct value as :

```
Printing description of dict:
{
    keyString =     (
        "<Entity: 0x7fa810e844d0>"
    );
},
```

but when i am passing this dictionary in watchkit extension delegate method via reply it crashes there SIGABRT

Answer (score 1):

sulabh, Since you have customEntityArray which is an array of custom Class Objects. That's why your application is crashing , you can't pass data from iOS application to watchkit extension via custom class. You have to avoid putting key values in custom class , try to pass key values from NSMutableDictionaries or by something else .

Comment: thanks anupam .
Actualy i had to pass large number of key values,
so instead of passing each value by adding new key - i wanted to send it in one shot . is there not any way to do it?